# Using records in functions

Tags: erlang

I was just playing with records, and am stuck trying to write a function that works with records. I think the problem is how to read the record definition into my module file.

The `reocords.hrl` file:

```
% Modeling a todo list
-record(todo, {status=reminder, who=joe, text}).
```

And then the `use_records.erl` file:

```
%% Use the records defined in "records.hrl"
-module(use_records).
-export([todo_to_tuple/1]).

rr("records.hrl").
todo_to_tuple(#todo{who=W, text=T} = R) -> {W, T}.
```

When I try to compile it, I get:

```
24> c(use_records).
use_records.erl:5: variable 'T' is unbound
use_records.erl:5: variable 'W' is unbound
use_records.erl:5: record todo undefined
use_records.erl:5: Warning: variable 'R' is unused
error
```

The error is the same if I remove the `rr("records.hrl")` line. So I suppose the real issue is being able to read the record definition (or not?). Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rr/1` is used include record definition only in the shell.

In order to include record definition in your code use:

```
-include("records.hrl")
```